# Google PHP API - (403) Access Not Configured

Tags: api, google-analytics

Im using the Google PHP API Client http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to retrieve data from the google API.

Logging in thru OAuth2 and fetch user information works like a charm, but when I'm attempting to access the goole analytics api i get this 403 code error every time. Hundreds of users with the same problem forgot to activate the Google Analytics API in the service settings, or simply provided incorrect credentials (client_id & client_secret). I've tried to enable/disable the Google Analytics multiple times, and logging in/out from my google accounts, but no result.

Anyone that has any pointers for me? 
(Remember, the OAuth procedure works, since I'm getting both an access_token and refresh_token)

I'm using the simple.php example in the class examples folder...

Comment: 1. Did u check if there is any ssl related issues?
2. Did u check if your quota has been exceed its limit?

Comment: I have similar problem - i have it working locally, but collecting this error response at my testing remote with the same credentials (i have both ip addresses allowed for the same developer key).
This is definitely not issue of quota, google responds by quota error message in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Drive myself and understand the issue. I've been having some troubles understanding Google and their PHP api somewhat. I've finally got it to work with some clarification of examples found around the internet.

Your problem sounds like you didn't set your scope to Google analytics but, please be clear in the steps you've taken as well as the code you've tried using.

The error could be as simple as forgetting this line in your oAuth callback file:

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS);
```

To something complex as understanding if you need a full paid account to access information from Google about your Analytics (not included as free like Google+ and Google drive).